# Why do .o files appear to have a .bss section of size 0 when compiled with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, static-libraries

While working on a C program, I altered my build to produce a .o file instead of a stand-alone binary. When doing so, I noticed that the size of the .bss section of the resulting .o file is 0, according to `readelf -S` even though there are clearly uninitialized globals in the source.

I can replicate this with a simple program, test.c:

```
char arr[42];
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  return 0;
}
```

The binary resulting from `gcc -o test test.c` has an eighty byte .bss section, according to readelf, which is roughly what I'd expect, as I expected some minor overhead.

However, if I build a .o file with `gcc -c -o test.o test.c`, the size of the bss section is reported as zero. Clearly I'm misunderstanding something about the nature of ELF object files, but I'm not quite sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What command are you using to get the section sizes? For me: `size test.o` reports a bss with a size of 42 bytes while `size test` reports 80 bytes

Comment: @Expolarity; in my case I used readelf. I see the same thing with size, however. RE: the size of 80, sorry, I accidentally forgot to convert from hexadecimal.

Comment: Oh, I think that readelf reports two different sets of sizes, one should be under the section name in the first column (named Size) and one in the second column (named EntSize). EntSize was often zeroed out. Is it perhaps possible you read the other size which was zero?

Comment: @Expolarity that's a good thought, but nope! It's the regular size field in the first column. I also double-checked with the ```size``` command, as well, to be sure.

Comment: note that gcc implements Annex J.5.11 which allows uninitialized globals to be conflated with an initialized global in another translation unit,  so this array might not end up in BSS at all in a final executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELF object files have a dummy .bss segment. They can not be loaded directly (unlike an executable or shared library).

The information about the global variables is stored in the .symtab section, which is used by the linker to construct the .bss and other sections in the final binary.

Try doing `readelf -s test.o` to reveal the symbol table.